# How to understand that the left regular representation of a division algebra is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, division-algebras

In Weyl's book *The classical groups*, it is said the regular representations of a division algebra are faithful and irreducible.

The key step is to show the ideal of the division algebra is $\{0\}$ and itself, i.e. if we have $u^{-1}$, we can prove that any element of the whole algebra belongs to the ideal.
Thus the subspace of left regular representation is the whole space.

My question is: we know that the regular representation of a finite group is reducible, which also have the inverse of an element $u^{-1}$. Seems that it's very close to a division algebra. Why do we get a different result?

Comment: Being a division algebra and being a simple algebra are not the same thing. In particular, the statement implicit in the question of your title is false.

Comment: Yes, division algebra is a special case of simple algebra. In Weyl's book, it is said, "Theorem (3.3.A) A division algebra is simple. Indeed its regular representation is irreducible as well as faithful". Also in his paper (Annals of Mathematics, vol 37, 709-405), it is said (Pg. 712), "the regular representation of a (a division algebra) is faithful as well as irreducible and hence a is simple". Thus the irreducibility should be the fundamental property of a simple algebra. Here I just show the proof of division algebra. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: Your title says that you want to understand the fact that «the left regular representation of a simple algebra is irreducible» and, as I said, it is *not* irreducible in general.

Comment: Oh, I am really confusing here. I had changed the title. So does a regular representation of division algebra irreducible? How can I understand it, especially when compare to the finite group? Thank you very much!@MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is this: a division ring over a field $k$ is already a $k$-vector space, while a group needs to be turned into a vector space to become a representation.

If we take a group $G$, then $G$ is simple as a $G$-set, in particular it is irreducible.  But there is no reason to conclude that $k[G]$ should be irreducible as a $G$-representation—all we can conclude is that any decomposition must involve some of the field structure, i.e. we cannot get a decomposition by just bunching together coordinates.

For example, take $G=C_2 = \langle g \mid g^2 = 1\rangle$.  The natural invariant basis of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is $\{e+g,e-g\}$, which involves structure not visible within $G$ itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a beginner and still have some questions. My question is, Seems that k[G] itself is a division ring, as we do have inverse here due to the property of group G. Thus the representation based on k[G] should be irreducible? And I am not actually understand "the structure not visible within G itself". Does the special structure  visible to division ring?@Slade

Comment: @LIU $k[G]$ is certainly not a division ring.  It has zero divisors, because $(e+g)(e-g) = e^2 - g^2 = e - e = 0$.  In particular, $e+g$ and $e-g$ do not have inverses.

Comment: @ Slade Thank you very much! So is there any possible situation that $k[G]$ is a division ring?For example, the abelian group of prime order,  $G=\{g,g^2,g^3=e\}$

Comment: $k[G]$ is a division ring exactly when tthe group is trivial.

Comment: @ MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Haha, of course it is.

Comment: @Slade I think I partially understand your point. Though for the group, the left regular representation $lx$ for $x\in G$ gives all the group elements due to the Rearrangement Theorem, we can not say that the subspace of left regular representation is the whole $k[G]$. Because this regular representation does not operate on the whole vector space $k[G]$, and only on a few points (the group elements). Thus the regular representation may still be reducible.